# Can't use backgroung-image correctly on bootstrap div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply a background-image into a div, it works but i am not able to put it correctly:

1. I have a space between the top of my div and the top of my background image, it has been reduce a lot by adding a `background-position: 0;` but it still have a space of many pixels.
2. I appy a `background-repeat: x;` (which is apparently the default state), but i have an important space between my images.

How could i solved these issues ?

Here is the html code using bootstrap:

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="header">
  <div id="bar" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#bar > .span12{
    position: relative;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    height: 8%;
    background-image:url('../img/ban.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:0;
}
```

Here is the result i get:

[image: Here is the result i get]

Thanks !

Comment: try this "body div#bar div.span12" instead "#bar > .span12"

Comment: I just tried, if i do that, the div disepear under the `background-color` of my `body`, even the borders.

Comment: is there padding in the way?

Comment: Well, Well you are messing with 2 backgounds, then only z-index can help you. Try to add z-index to your inner div. 

Add This --   "z-index:50"

Comment: that's because i have other div previously, why do you wan to start from the body since i have an id in my DOM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This image was kind of corrupted, i tried with another one just because i didn't see any solution and it worked, maybe transparant background, i don't know but it came from the image...

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with `background-position:0 !important;`? Maybe the property it's getting overwritten.

Comment: I just made a test, it doesn't change anything...

I have built a new page with just the code i show here so i don't have any other css properties written in my file